# How set hover for featured image? How change hover?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to set the gif file in the featured image. I would like it to run when I hover over it with the mouse.

I know I should set this in functions.php file

Together with the code:

```
add_theme_support ('post-thumbnails');
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it. I create my blog and I have never done such things. Could someone help me how to do it?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload an animated GIF to WordPress, it does all of it’s resizing magic to make the various thumbnail sizes (defaults are thumbnail, **medium** and **large**, in addition to the original **full**). When it does this, the resized versions lose their animation.

If your theme displays featured images at any size other than **full**, you’ll thusly lose your **GIF’s** animation.

If you definitely know that you want to display the animated version, though, there’s a little trick you can use.

```
<?php $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
      $thumb_low = strtolower($thumb_url);
      if (strpos($thumb_low, '.gif') === false) {
        $thumb_size = 'large';
      } else {
        $thumb_size = 'full';
      } 
?>
```

What am I doing here is getting the URL of our featured image, then I make sure it’s all lower case letters (WordPress may do this anyway, but just to be safe), then I check to see if **.gif** is present in the thumbnail’s URL, and finally, if it is, I set the thumbnail size I use to ‘large’. Doing so will allow me to use the original image, which retains it’s animation.

Then, I just need to tell our call to `the_post_thumbnail()` to use the variable thumbnail size we set, like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail($thumb_size)
```

Comment: ok I understand, but how I can set hover? I have a static image when I click a post, now mouseover image and gif start. Can I make this ?

Comment: Ok for doing this you have to add a custom field just for gif and than create two images tag, one for static image and one for gif, than on mouseover display the gif.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show me how I can do this ? in functions.php, because I don't know, thanks for your time. Maybe we can add this to your code ?

Comment: Are you using any plugin to create Custom Fields?

Comment: No, I'm not. I make this with any plugin ? hover in featured image ?

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve ever tried to set an animated **gif** as a featured image in WordPress, you’ve probably discovered that you can’t.

The reason why is ***pretty simple***. Your theme grabs a resized version of the featured image you upload. And *in the case of an animated gif, that means it’s not grabbing the original gif image, and so you end up with a static image.*

The way around this is pretty simple, however. You can just install a plugin that automatically sets the featured image from the first image in a post. Of course that means you will need to make the animated image the first image, but at least it’s a workaround.

There are a number of plugins that will let you automatically set your first image as the featured image. I tried two and the both worked: [Autoset Featured Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoset-featured-image/) and [Automatic Featured Image Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/).

*Something else I found was that I didn’t even need to download the **gif**. I could just insert it with the `URL`.*